# Причина предупреждения при работе с бд android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Выскакивает предупреждение при работе с бд, я так понял что нужно закрывать бд после записи, но я вроде все закрываю но почему-то все-равно ошибка появляется. Не могу понять что не так делаю.

```
A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.example.developer_4.test_login/databases/selected_jobs_L' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

вот запись в бд:

```
public void insertNote(Integer job_id, String job_date,String job_time) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Job.COLUMN_JOB_ID, job_id);
        values.put(Job.COLUMN_JOB_DATE, job_date);
        values.put(Job.COLUMN_JOB_TIME, job_time);

        db.insert(Job.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
```

и вот проверяю наличие записи в бд:

```
public boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String fieldValue) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String Query = "Select * from " + Job.TABLE_NAME + " where " + Job.COLUMN_JOB_ID + " = " + fieldValue;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Я думаю как раз вам выскакивает сообщение о том, что вы закрываете подключение к БД, когда могут идти другие операции чтения/записи. Можно на код посмотреть?

Comment: Перенесите инициализацию и закрытие БД в application. И вам не нужно будет беспокоиться о таких вещах, как открытие и закрытие бд. 
И еще из плюсов, что у вас везде будет использоваться один экземпляр БД.

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский, дело в том что я использую бд в адаптере списка и не могу все перенсти в application :(

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko я не уверен что у вас правильная логика. Адаптер должен выполнять одну функцию это отображение списка. В вашем случае получается что он стучит к бд(если она не открыта, еще её открывает, потом закрывает), так как вызовы к бд должны быть еще асинхронными, то еще и это. Хотя правильней было бы это перенести в презентер(MVP) или viewModel(MVVM) и после адаптеру передать просто список для отображения

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский, я не спорю что у меня возможно оооочень кривая логика, но по ней получается так - если нажимаю на элемент списка, то данные этого элемента добавляются в бд, и дальше уже при заполнении элементами список, я проверяю был ли нажат элемент, и если да, то выделяю его, не очень представляю как это все можно закинуть в активность

Comment: Если вам нужно реализовать выделение списка, рекомендую использовать ActionMode.  Я введу к тому что, если вы планируете дальше улучшать ваше приложение, было бы экономней по времени это переписать и разбить на отдельные блоки. Это уменьшит количество ошибок, а так же улучшит чтения кода.

Comment: Можете более уточнить что вы имеете в виду, или офрмите в качестве ответа и он будет рабочим, то я его с радостью прийму, потому что сейчас я ковыряюсь с закрытием бд и не очень получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно решение не очень правильное, и найдутся люди которые будут его критиковать, но мне кажется помогло (или нет, я в процессе тестирования не замечал больше такой ошибки), в DataBaseHelper класс нужно вставить такую конструкцию:

```
  public static DataBaseHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DataBaseHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
```

и теперь после этого, при вызове функции записи например я пишу так:

```
DataBaseHelper.getInstance(ctx).insertNote(job_id, date, job_time);
```

то есть вставляю это:

```
 DataBaseHelper.getInstance(ctx)
```

надеюсь что это поможет не только мне решить свою проблему.

Comment: Так помогло или нет?

Comment: да мне это решенеи помогло)

Answer (score 2):

Ваше предупреждение говорит о том, что вы закрываете соединение с БД, но т.к. процесс открытия/закрытия требует времени, можно повредить данные БД, если в этот момент другой метод выполнял запись в БД. Так же ваше приложение может вылетать, если вы поочередно сделаете закрытие и открытие подключения к БД в разных методах.

Откройте подключение к бд в onCreate, и не закрывайте его.

Если есть шанс того, что в БД не будут обращаться и вы хотите сэкономить ресурсы устройства, то можно в отдельном методе проверять открыто ли подключение к БД, и если не открыто то открывать.

Прочитайте ответы по этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557154)